# KeyBinding with no modifiers (in UserControl)

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to execute a command when a key pressed(without modifiers). So, I tried below code:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="A" Command="{Binding ACommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

but, KeyBinding supports not a key but key and modifier.

Now I consider using Behavior and treat KeyDown event. But this is too complex.

Someone knows an easier solution?

**Add:** 
Above code is work well **in Window**.

I find solution in UserControl. (Using .NET Framework 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not quite get what your problem is. The code you wrote **should work**, there is no need to specify modifiers.

I suppose the problem might be your binding or the control you set the key binding on cannot be focused so it won't trigger.

Comment: Thank you, but that code is valid in FUNCTION KEYs only. I want to binding command to normal key, such as 'A', or 'R'....

Comment: That is not true, it works for all keys. I have used it many times for normal keys as well.

Comment: If you don't believe that you can try the "proper" way by setting `Modifiers="None"`.

Comment: Modifiers="None" are cannot convert to valid Modifiers. 

According to MSDN, "a valid KeyGesture must contain exactly one Key and one or more ModifierKeys". ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx )

Comment: I know, but that is referring to KeyGestures, i.e. `KeyGesture="A"` would be invalid while setting `Key="A"` on its own works.

Comment: Actually, that does not make all too much sense, it says `KeyGesture` just sets it in one string but is equivalent. That being said i have no idea why the documentation claims that modifiers are needed since it always worked for me...

Comment: OK, I got some proceeding. This is work in Window.KeyBinding. But (OtherControl e.g. UserControl, Grid, etc).KeyBinding is not work(work only KeyBinding with Modifiers).

Comment: Where you specify your keybinding just sets the scope, if you set it in your control your control **needs to both be focusable and in focus while you press the key.**

Comment: Yeah, just it!　I am very sorry to have troubled you so much. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft doesn't support binding to a normal key that you might press while typing in a text box - unless it has a modifier.  You can bind to function keys (like F1) and a few others without a modifier.
See: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keygesture(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keygesture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I've come across a blog that says he was able to get around this problem by creating his own KeyGesture class by inheriting from InputGesture and implementing the Matches function.  http://dikhi.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/keygesture-doesnt-work-with-alpha-numeric-key/

Answer (score 1):

I figured a way out to set a InputBinding by using only a single Key like "Key.A"

```
boolean noMod = ModifierKeys == ModifierKeys.None;
KeyBinding inputBinding = new KeyBinding(this, Keys, noMod ? ModifierKeys.Alt : ModifierKeys));
if (noMod)
{
    inputBinding.ClearValue(KeyBinding.ModifiersProperty);
}
```

That worked for me fine.